# A function for finding normal edge-5-colorings of cubic graphs

Tags: graphs-and-networks

It would be nice if the following were available:

> **Definition** A *normal edge-k-coloring* of a cubic graph $G$ is a proper edge-$k$-coloring of the graph such that for any edge $e\in E(G)$, $e$ and the edges adjacent to it are colored using either five colors, or only three colors.

Would there be an implementation in Mathematica to find minimum normal edge-$k$-colorings of cubic graphs?  Note that, theory says that if a graph has a bridge, $k$ might have to be 7, but if it is bridgeless, it is conjectured that there are normal edge-5-colorings.  And of course, if $G$ is class 1, then it has a normal edge-3-coloring.  For those who practice edge coloring programming, this is probably not easy.  Ideally, there is a function to find normal edge-5-colorings of cubic bridgeless graphs when they exist.  For more information about normal colorings, look at [1].

[1] Mazzuoccolo, G., and Mkrtchyan, V., Normal edge-colorings of cubic graphs, arXiv:1804.09449v2

Comment: IGraph/M has a function to find $k$-edge-colorings. If you want the additional requirement you mention, I'm afraid you will need to implement that yourself. Your problem is very specific and narrow, it's not something one would find implemented in an existing general-purpose graph theory package.

Comment: Can't you simply take the line graph, then do vertex colouring on that? If 3 colours are enough, you're done. If it gives you 4 colours, then take the neighbours of each vertex, and connect them to each other. Re-do the vertex colouring. It should result in a 5-colouring.

Comment: `g = PetersenGraph[]; lg = LineGraph[g]`, then `extraEdges = 
  Join @@ (UndirectedEdge @@@ Subsets[#, {2}] & /@ 
     Values@IGAdjacencyList[lg]); IGMinimumVertexColoring@SimpleGraph@EdgeAdd[lg, extraEdges]`

Comment: @Szabolcs Great!  This seems to work with Petersen.  However, I need to verify this works with other graphs, when I get a little time.  I need to digest what you are doing and think about it.  There would be graphs when you need edges such that the edge and its adjacent edges need 3 colors rather than 5.  But I need to find such example when I get back to this fully on Tuesday.    Question:  will this always give you a 5-coloring, or might it end up using more colors.

Comment: Why the downvotes?  This is a legitimate question and not an easy one.  I am a fairly new user to this site, please someone explain the rationale ... that way, I will not post questions which people are not interested in reading.  Already an answer in a comment is useful, and another answer which was posted and deleted also had pieces of Mathematica wisdom which were useful to me.

Comment: @Bill Combinatorica does not have this, unfortunately.

Comment: @Szabolcs As I said, let me do some checking, and also wait for your answer.  If this solves the problem, might you consider posting it as an answer.  I will send a comment again after I have tested this extensively on Tuesday.

Comment: @Szabolcs Right, I checked quickly ... this will produce a 6 coloring sometimes.  So although each edge and its adjacent edges will use 5 colors, you might need 6 colors to do this with your algorithm.  The point is to use only 5, while still having a proper edge coloring, AND one which is normal.  I will post the example when I get back ...

Comment: Yeah, that's why I didn't post it as an answer ... I thought something _might_ go wrong.

Comment: @EGME The downvote is not from me (to the contrary), but I guess somebody found it annoying that (i) you posted a nonstandard research problem (ii) without explaining the basic concepts (the readers have to look up a lot for themselves) and (iii) without any _Mathematica_ code. This is not seldomly interpreted as lack of effort. As is, this question is not related at all to _Mathematica_ (apart from "give me the codz plz"). In general, it is a quite bold request to ask for an implementation in a specific language when the authors of the research paper did not bother to provide any algorithm...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thank you! Well, the question is as standard or non-standard as the reader might consider - Mathematica goes deeply into some topics; the basic concepts are self contained in the definition that I provided (the reference is extra); and the idea was to find out if there is an implementation already available, not provide code - for example, although I am familiar with what IGraph does, I don’t know everything about it.  I would not try to duplicate the usual edge coloring function, for example, or this normal-edge-coloring function if it were available  - continued

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I do not know the details of any algorithm of either the usual edge coloring function or this one.  But it seems maybe I have to develop an algorithm for this, and implement it, unless someone tells me how this is done or that it is available, something I do not know, and the reason why I ask.  This is by the way, not such an unusual function as to consider it non-standard research ... all that having been said, I liked what you had posted but got removed ... I had not been able to thank you and I do so now.

Comment: @Szabolcs Right, I got a moment to think more about your function.  I am pretty certain that what it does is find what is called a minimum strong edge coloring.  It is going to be normal, but not minimum normal in general.  I don’t know if one can start out with this coloring and modify it into a minimum normal edge coloring.  I will give this some thought.  Thanks once again.